# Auto classification of my bank transactions

Tags: python, machine-learning

This is my first Machine Learning algorithm using Python and SkLearn. The code works, which is pretty awesome. I'm getting about 65-70% of accuracy after training it with about 4k rows of data.

Although it works, it seems like is less than optimal. I'm guessing it would be better to organize it with functions and etc - I don't know - it just seems that is more complex than it should be...

**Pre processing**

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/class_full.csv',
                    encoding='latin1',
                    error_bad_lines=False,
                    delimiter=';')

# Define column names & Change label to Pandas "Category"
data.columns  = ['desc', 'value', 'label']
data['desc'] = data['desc'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
data['label'] = data['label'].astype('category')

# Assign data as "string"
labels   = data['label'].values.astype(str)
feature1 = data['desc'].values.astype(str)

# Vectorizes strings with Tf-IDF Vectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors    = vectorizer.fit_transform(feature1)   # Train Data
vectors_   = vectorizer.transform(feature1)       # Test Data
```

**Fitting the model**

```
#Test
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = tts(vectors, labels, test_size=0.05)

# ExtraTree Classifier
print('\nEstimating score with ExtraTree Classifier...')
extra_model = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=10, random_state=42)
extra_model.fit(train_features, train_labels)
predictions_extra = extra_model.predict(vectors_)
print('Score: {:.2f}'.format(extra_model.score(test_features, test_labels)*100) + ' ExtraTree Classifier')
```

**Print accuracy**

```
# Print of all results
print('Score: {:.2f}'.format(extra_model.score(test_features, test_labels)*100)    + ' ExtraTree Classifier\n')

# Voting Classifier
eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('extra', extra_model)], voting='soft')

for clf, label in zip([extra_model, eclf], ['Extra']):

     scores = cross_val_score(clf, test_features, test_labels, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
     print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f) [%s]" % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), label))
```

**Make Predictions**

```
# Statement to be classified
statement = pd.read_csv('data/extrato.csv',
                    encoding='latin1',
                    error_bad_lines=False,
                    delimiter=',')

# Defining the column and vectorizing it
newFeatures     = statement['memo'].values.astype(str)
newVectorizer   = TfidfVectorizer()
newVector       = newVectorizer.fit_transform(newFeatures)
newVector_      = newVectorizer.transform(newFeatures)

# Predictions with Random Forest, Decision Tree & SVC models
predictions_extra = extra_model.predict(vectorizer.transform(newFeatures))
predictions_extra  = numpy.asarray(predictions_extra)
predictions_extra  = pd.DataFrame(predictions_extra)

# Finding probabilities for each of the assigned categories
extra_prob = extra_model.predict_proba(vectorizer.transform(newFeatures))
extra_prob = numpy.asarray(extra_prob)
extra_prob = pd.DataFrame(extra_prob)
extra_prob = extra_prob.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Imports are missing. And we can't run the code without input data.

Comment: Could you make it clearer whether the code is in a single file or multiple? If it's a single file, please combine the code blocks into a single code block and add comments to delimit sections as necessary. If you need the section headers to stand out, you could try surrounding it with `#`s: `###########[newline]# Section #[newline]###########`